# Table-cell with position relative and content absolute bug in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-tables

I really don't know what's the problem with my code...

The cell is positioned relative and the form is positioned absolute. In every browsers it works as it should but not Firefox...

Does it have problems with table CSS?

**CSS**

```
.table                              { display: table; width:100%; height:100%; table-layout: fixed; }
.row                                { display: table-row; height: 1px; }
.cell                               { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; position: relative; }
.menu .cell                         { width: 33.33%; border: 1em solid #000; font-size: 1.14em;
                                    background: #fff; background-clip: padding-box; vertical-align: top; position: relative; }

.menu .cell header                  { padding:.5em 1em; background-color: #383430; color: #fff; line-height: 1.2; position: relative; }
.menu .cell .content                { padding:2em 1em 3em 1em;}
.menu .cell h3                      { font-size: 1em; text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: underline; font-weight:300;} 
.menu .cell ul                      { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
.menu .cell li                      { line-height: 1.4; padding:0.25em 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #ecece6;}
.menu .cell li:last-child           { border-bottom: none; margin-bottom: 0;}



.menu .like header:before           { content : 'on aime !'; position: absolute; bottom: 100%; left: 1em; 
                                    text-transform: uppercase; font-size: .8em; padding: 3.5em .5em .5em .5em; border-radius: 1em 1em 0 0; 
                                    background: #dd582a url(imgs/on-aime.png) center .5em no-repeat; box-shadow:  0px 0px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5); }


.menu .favorite                     { position: absolute; bottom: -.75em; right: -.75em;  display: block; width: 100%; overflow: hidden;}
.menu .favorite input               { position: absolute; top: -30em;}

.menu .favorite label,
.menu .favorite label:before        { background-color: #dd582a; height: 32px; white-space: nowrap;
                                    float: right;  color: #fff; background-image: linear-gradient(#dd582a 50%, #bd5d3b 100%); }
.menu .favorite label:hover,
.menu .favorite label:hover:before{background-image: linear-gradient(#bd5d3b 5%, #dd582a 50%); }

.menu .favorite label               { text-align: center; font-size: 24px; width: 32px; display: block; 
                                    line-height: 28px; border-radius: 4px; cursor: pointer;}

.menu .favorite label:before        { content: "Add to favorite"; display: block; position: absolute; right: 34px;
                                    padding:0 8px; font-size: 14px; line-height:32px  }
.menu .favorite input:checked + label { color: #e77248; background-color: #fff;background-image: linear-gradient(#ffffff 50%, #bfbfbf 100%); }
.menu .favorite input:checked + label:hover{background-image: linear-gradient(#bfbfbf 5%, #fff 50%);}
.menu .favorite input:checked + label:before { content: "Like"}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="table menu">

    <div class="row">
<div class="cell">
    <div >
        <header>100 $</header>
        <div class="content">
            <h3>Title 1</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 4</li>
                <li>Item 5</li>
                <li>Item 6</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <form class="favorite">
            <input id="bal-menu2" type="checkbox" name="bal-menu2" value="favorite" />
            <label for="bal-menu2">♥</label>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
        <div class="cell">
    <div >
        <header>100 $</header>
        <div class="content">
            <h3>Title 1</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 4</li>
                <li>Item 5</li>
                <li>Item 6</li>
                <li>Item 7</li>
                <li>Item 8</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <form class="favorite">
            <input id="bal-menu2" type="checkbox" name="bal-menu2" value="favorite" />
            <label for="bal-menu2">♥</label>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
    </div></div>
```

Here's a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/warface/8bWUe/2/

Look in firefox, you'll notice that the form "add to favorite" stack on each other but in other browser it positioned just fine.

Any clues on how to make it work has it should like in Chrome, Safari, IE8+,...?

**EDIT**

After some research... Firefox has this problem since 2000

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63895

And they don't seem to give a middle finger about it to fix it... burn in hell Firefox !

Comment: I viewed your fiddle in Firefox and while the `form.favorite` element falls off the bottom of my screen, I do see both of its children next to each other.  Can you please clarify what the problem is?

Comment: have you seen it in Chrome or any other browser ??? This is how I want it. I thought it was clear in the question sorry

Answer (score 4):

Here's a fix that takes the modified .cell >div {position:relative} and add height:100% to the divs.

**CSS**

```
.row { display: table-row; height:100%; }
.cell div {height:100%; position: relative }
```

Here's the udpated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8bWUe/19/

Works on FF v22.0

Answer (score 0):

Make

```
.row
{
      display: block; 
      position:relative
}
```

instead of "`table-row`" - that should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get the forms placed in firefox with the following css:

> .cell > div { position: relative }

Comment: It's not working I've tried it just put the form under the content instead of the cells.

Comment: You're right; I was more trying to get you a bit closer to the solution but I can't comment on your question without more rep. So this isn't really an answer. I'll have a look again and see if I can get things more like you want

Comment: Good luck hehe. Been 5 hours I'm trying different way... starting to think that Firefox simply sucks for table-cell positioning and will have to change my code for floating elements with defined height...